# No Navigation Editor in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio

I have installed the latest version (2.0) of Android Studio, but when I go to **tools-android**, I can't see **Navigation Editor**.

Should I download it as a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Android Studio Project Site](http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor)

> **Navigation Editor isn't available in Android Studio starting from version 2.0.** It was an experimental feature and we may re-visit it in the future.

It was there in Android Studio 1.5.1.

Comment: Now i got it. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could assist - you can accept the answer if it addresses you question.